# Rails: Correct Way of Using the method of PostController in the Index file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I'd like to learn how to use the methods defined in the controller in the index page.
I'm trying to implement "like" button on my blog.

**PostController**

```
def like
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.like += 1
@post.save
end
```

In the index where all the posts are listed, I tried something like this.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= post.name %></td>
  <td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %I:%M%p") %></td>
  <td><%= post.view %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'like', like_post_path %></td>
  <td>hate</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I got the idea by looking at the code,

```
<%= link_to 'make a new post', new_post_path %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
```

I thought the way to use methods in the controller in the index page was 
**(method in PostController)_post_path**, but it seems I got it wrong.

```
undefined local variable or method `like_post_path'
```

I've also tried like(post).

My ultimate goal is to make this function as an ajax function, so I expected it to be a form like

```
<% link_to_function 'like', like_post, remote: true %>
```

**What's the right way of using the method "like" in this case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to define a named route to make this work.  Like:

```
# in config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'like'
  end

  # OR
  get 'like', :on => :member
end

# in `rake routes` this would show up as:
like_post GET    /posts/:id/like(.:format)  posts#like

# you'd reference in a view like:
like_post_path(@post)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Could you explain further about "member do" part? Also, could you tell me how "edit" and "new" methods are routed like this but not shown in the config/routes.rb file?

Comment: `resources` is a macro for `edit` and `new`, as well as the other REST methods.  Inside the `resources` block you can define "member" routes, which create routes pointing to an individual record by id, and "collection" routes, which do not.  Further explanation can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)