# Rails: Using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Problem: **Trying to implement "like" function on my blog**

**PostIndex:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td><%= post.name %></td>
<td><%= link_to post.content, post %></td>
<td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %I:%M%p") %></td>
<td><%= post.view %></td>
<td><%= post.like %></td>
<td><%= post.hate %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'like', like_post_path(post), :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**PostController:**

```
def like
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.like += 1
 @post.save

 respond_to do |format|
    format.js
 end
end
```

**app/views/posts/like.js.erb**

```
$('#post').html("<%=j @post.like %>");
```

**Question:**

I believe I'm not correctly pointing at the post I'm looking at in like.js.erb.

In the index file, Simply doing <%= @post.view  %> worked. But how do you do it in like.js.erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some identifier for post's like count in your html when you want to update it after ajax call

**PostIndex:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to post.content, post %></td>
    <td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %I:%M%p") %></td>
    <td><%= post.view %></td>
    <td id= "post<%= post.id %>_like"><%= post.like %></td>  <!-- set id (identifier) here -->
    <td><%= post.hate %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'like', like_post_path(post), :remote => true %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

then in your **app/views/posts/like.js.erb**,

```
<% if @post.errors.blank? %>
  $("#post<%= @post.id %>_like").html("<%=j @post.like %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have edited my code. Hey please do check @post.errors is blank and validations are not failing if you added some validations on Post model.

Comment: It works! I'm assuming there was a typo in the index file. Thank you!

Comment: One minor error. If you do as written in here, only the top row of the table keeps getting updated. So when you define the row id, you have to add a component that is specific to the post. (in this case, post.id)

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Way of Using Ajax to Fix a Table Row:**

In your show.html (or index.html) file, you probably have a table already.

```
<tr>
 <td>row 1</td>
 <td>row 2</td>
 <td>row 3</td>
</tr>
```

Let's pretend the rows represent some kind of variable. Then the table above would be like,

```
<tr>
 <td><%= @variableA %></td>
 <td><%= @variableB %></td>
 <td><%= @variableC %></td>
</tr>
```

I want to change variableA without reloading the whole page. So I use Ajax.

My method:

```
def fixvar
 @variableA = 2
end
```

You have to add one component to use Ajax.

```
def fixvar
 @variableA = 2
end

respond_to do |format|
 format.js
end
```

And wherever you want, you will have a link that will invoke the change via ajax.

```
<%= link_to 'change variable A', URLof_fixvar(@variableA), :remote => true %>
```

By using the option :remote => true, you're using an ajax component in your link_to method. You have to set URLof_fixvar in config/routes.rb accordingly. [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328453/rails-correct-way-of-using-the-method-of-postcontroller-in-the-index-file/13328525#13328525)

Let's specify where to update in the table.

```
<tr>
 <td id="variable_change_<%= @variableA.id %>><%= @variableA %></td>
 <td><%= @variableB %></td>
 <td><%= @variableC %></td>
</tr>
```

We did as above to specify the row that we're trying to update. For example, the row is now defined as variable_change_1. (assuming variableA.id is 1)

Now, you need to go to the related views folder, and create a .js.erb file that relates to the defined method above. For example, I had "like" method defined in my PostController, so I created

```
app/views/posts/like.js.erb
```

In here, you only  need one line of code:

```
$("#variable_change_<%= @variable.id %>").html("<%= @variableA %>");
```

The first part before .html is pointing at the specified row, and the part after is the value that we want to update. Done!